# Gridview Datasource Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

my requirement is that i want all the data from database should bind to the
grid view without updating the grid view data source....

Here is my code:-

```
public void BindAll(GridView grd)
        {
            List<int> id = new List<int>();
            SqlCommand cmd =new SqlCommand("Select SiteId from SiteMaster",con);

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr =cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                id.Add(Convert.ToInt16(dr["SiteId"]));

            }
            dr.Close();
            foreach (int k in id)
            {
            List<Errorlog> lst = new List<Errorlog>();
            DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();
            param.Add("SiteId",k, DbType.Int16);
            lst = con.Query<Errorlog>("Usp_Temp", param, null, true, 200, CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
            if (lst.Count != 0)
            {

                grd.DataSource = lst; //here it display only those record which are last updated.I am binding data from multiple table .it only display last table data.I want all the data from all the table should be display.
                grd.DataBind();
            }


            }

        }
```

Comment: I you don't want update the lst only call once :  List<Errorlog> lst = new List<Errorlog>();  You are creating a new list each time which removed the old data.  Also when updating set datasource to null : grd.DataSource = null;grd.DataSource = lst;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Errorlog> lst = new List<Errorlog>(); // create list 
// loop and add items to above list as below
foreach (int k in id)
{
    DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();
    param.Add("SiteId",k, DbType.Int16);
    List<Errorlog> temp= con.Query<Errorlog>("Usp_Temp", param, null, true, 200, CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
    //add to main list
    lst .AddRange(temp);

}
//finally show all the data
if (lst.Count != 0)
{
    grd.DataSource = lst; 
    grd.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
SqlCommand cmd =new SqlCommand("Select * from SiteMaster",con);
```

I' ve changed the sql query